# How to SQL query posts IDs by categories AND authors?

Tags: wp-query, query, sql

I am making a custom WP_Query and I need to come up with a SQL query that gets the posts IDs from X categories and Y authors. Then merge those IDs and put them in an array.

I only need to figure out the SQL query. Everything else, I got it.

I have looked everywhere for this but no one has been able to help me. Please help me out!!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution :P but this could help you:

```
select 
    distinct(p.ID)
from
    wp_posts p,
    wp_term_relationships r,
    wp_term_taxonomy tt,
    wp_terms t
WHERE
    p.post_author in (1, 2, 3)
        and r.object_id = p.ID
        and tt.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
        and tt.taxonomy = 'category'
        and tt.term_id = t.term_id
        and t.term_id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am lookning for something like: SELECT distinct posts id FROM posts WHERE category id AND user id

Comment: Great, i will try that when i get home.

Comment: Ok :) http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters i think this is even better to solve your problem.